# How to tell if current time is the exact same as timestamp right down to the millisecond?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am sending a timestamp from the server and I want the browser to know when that exact time is.

I am using Moment but feel there are a few ways to achieve this.

I have looked at using `isSame()` in a `setInterval()` but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    if(moment().isSame(moment(data.server_time_stamp))){
        console.log('MATCHES!!!')
        clearInterval(interval)
    }

}, 1)
```

Where `data.server_time_stamp` is a moment object passed from the server (Calculated as current time + 10 seconds). I have set this to `utc()` in order to standardize the timezones on server and client.

I have also tried setting it to `unix()` and in my `setInterval()` loop, using `===` operator to see if they are the same. Like so:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){

  if(cur_time === data.screenshot_time){
   console.log('MATCHES!!!')
   clearInterval(interval)
  }

}, 1)
```

all though  with this method, it doesn't seem to be acurate enough.

What is the most accurate way to messure this?

Comment: A user's computer can have their clock set to any time, you cannot rely on the browser's time being the same as your server's. And you definitely cannot achieve millisecond precision using unix timestamps, which are accurate to 1 second.

Comment: Even if your server and client is synchronized, the event might not happen exactly at the millisecond that you want to, and therefore it will never match. And setInterval is not executed every millisecond.

Comment: You will never know when the event of setInterval will fire. For example Chrome limit how often events are fired when the tab is inactive. You could store the time you want, and then compare if that time has passed. You don't need a library for that.

Comment: Clock synchronization is not an easy problem.  Maybe you could explain why you think you need to do this and there might be another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: @gforce301 I have several browsers listening to an event via sockets. When a button is pushed on the admin panel, that sends an event to the server to tell it to emit a timestamp to all clients listening. The clients listening all need to take a screenshot at the exact same time. I will be in control of these browsers so can ensure the clocks are sync'd. I have added the 3 second buffer to ensure the requests are sent to each client in time and then all the client has to do is wait and compare current time === timestamp recieved.

Comment: "At the exact same time" is not going to happen. If you are already "sure" that the clocks are sync'd, why not just do the operation as soon as you get the message?

Comment: @gforce301 Perhaps exact time is not going to happen but I am trying to find a method for closest possible. And they won't all receive the event at the same rate. Therefore, the buffer is there to make sure all clients have received the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I ended up using (but am yet to thoroughly test) was using timesync to sync all clocks and then match the current time in a setInterval()

```
var ts = timesync.create({
    server: SERVER + '/timesync'
});

var interval = setInterval(function(){

    if(moment(ts.now()).utc().unix() === data.screenshot_time){
        console.log('SNAPPED!!!')
        take_photo()
        clearInterval(interval)
    }

}, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the seconds not the milliseconds like  @some said.
It could work like that:

```
moment.utc().isSame(moment(data.server_time_stamp), 'second');
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my issue for using isSame. I didn't have the `isSame()` argument set as a moment object.

Comment: There would be the possibility to use isSameOrAfter. This would work if both moments have the same milliseconds or if the current time is a few milliseconds after the data.server_time_stamp.